# Indian standards Mobile Number Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Create a custom module for Magento 2 where it needs to validate billing mobile numbers as per Indian standards, where it doesn't allow more than 10 digits including 0

Answer (score 0):

1).First of all,you need to create di.xml file at app/code/Vendor\Extension/etc/frontend/ and paste the below code to add plugin :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger">
        <plugin name="ph_checkout_phone_number"
                type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Block\Checkout\PhonePlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2)Now, Create PhonePlugin.php file at app/code/Vendor\Extension/Plugin/Block/Checkout/ and paste the below code to add validation code :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Block\Checkout;
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger;
class PhonePlugin
{
    /**
     * @param AttributeMerger $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterMerge(AttributeMerger $subject, $result)
    {
        $result['telephone']['validation'] = [
            'required-entry'  => true,
            'max_text_length' => 10,
            'validate-number' => true
        ];
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Here 3 rule added in phone number field.

1. Required Entry
2. Max Text Length
3. Input Validation.